# Use proxy_pass based if special header set otherwise use static files in Nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http

Is there a way in Nginx to serve always static file specified in `root` except for the case when request is matched according to some criteria (i.e. specified header) in which case it would be passed to an upstream ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this would work, obviously you'd have to flesh out your the proxy section. You could also wrap the `if` block in a location block.

```
   ...
    root /path/to/static/content;
    index static_content.html;

    if($http_x_yourheader_here) {
        proxy_pass upstream_addr;
    }
    ...
```